# Order holidays by month and day, instead of year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to order the holidays by month and day instead of by year first. `SELECT * FROM 'holidays' ORDER BY 'date' ASC` simply won't do. It returns the below results:

```
id date       holiday
2  2015-07-04 Independence Day
1  2016-01-01 New Years
3  2016-01-16 Pongal
```

The intended results will return:

```
id date       holiday
1  2016-01-01 New Years
3  2016-01-16 Pongal
2  2015-07-04 Independence Day
```

Comment: 'date' is a string - and, curiously, so is 'holidays'

Comment: as far as I know you can't really do that, or at least not in an efficient way, if youur date column is 'date' type. Storing year, month and day in separe columns would be much easier

Comment: `SELECT * FROM holidays ORDER BY MONTH(date), DAY(date)` isn't good?

Comment: aron9forever storing them as separate fields is almost always the wrong answer.